# Does IE9 support Touch events on Windows 7?

Tags: html, touch

I am trying to use touch events (i.e. touch move) on a Windows 7 based tablet PC to draw on a canvas element. I was wondering if IE9 DOM supports touch events. It would be great if anyone can point me to some sample code too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no touch event in IE9. I think many people have suggested this to the IE team during IE9's preview phase but they just didn't do it. Thus all you can get is mouse events.

Here's some reference:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/iewebdevelopment/thread/e747bc2b-671b-48b3-820b-889e11fdfaa5