# Cancel IE9 touch scroll event and invoke Mousemove, possible?

Tags: javascript, touch, internet-explorer-9, dom-events

On a Windows 7 computer with IE9 and a multitouch screen, like an HP TouchSmart, if you touch the screen on a page that is tall enough to have a scrollbar and move your finger up or down the page scrolls. This doesn't seem to fire any `mousemove` event. If you touch the screen and initially move left or right instead of up and down it does fire the `mousemouse` events.

I wan't to cancel this scrolling and cause the browser to invoke a normal `mousemove` event. Is this possible?

EDIT: There does not appear to be touch events in IE9 [Does IE9 support Touch events on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588517/does-ie9-support-touch-events-on-windows-7)

EDIT 2:
A couple other points of interest about this. First is that browsers often fire a `mousewheel` event when scrolling is triggered by a gesture, this can often be caught and cancelled. Second is that in this particular case, you can prevent the scrolling on IE9 with this hack `$(document).bind('mousedown mouseup click dblclick', function (e) { });` which as hacks sometimes do, does not make any sense to me - it may be possible to use fewer event bindings but I didn't have good access to a device to easily test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time testing the various methods to suppress default event responses, I have no idea how to suppress the scroll event.  You should, however, be able to fire the mousemove event from within a scroll event handler.

```
window.onscroll = function(e){
    element.onmousemove();
}

//jquery
$(window).scroll(function(e){ element.mousemove(); } );
```

A [primitive example](http://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/Jxqyw/5/).

Two things I suppose you could try to prevent auto-scroll: setting the overflow (or overflow-y) to hidden on you body element or as part of your onscroll handler, attempting to scroll back to your point of origin.  Setting body's overflow to hidden will prevent scrolling and hide the scrollbar, but I'm not sure it's what you want.

Comment: If mousemove fires based on scroll then it wouldn't be correct if moving left to right because even though its in scroll mode, the left to right mousemove is still needed. Correct me if you disagree. The overflow-y might be the best option. Do you know if I set a `<div>` to 100% height and overflow-y if that will be touch scrollable? It isn't on some real touch devices, so that might be an ok solution.

Comment: The div itself will not be scrollable.  However, block-level elements do not default to height: 100% (they default, to height: auto), so you would need to make sure that the parent element had its height set explicitly.  If that parent is to be body, scrolling will be disabled, but some touch devices (the iPad for certain) define their viewport as being larger than the layout.  If that becomes an issue, I would point you to the excellent quirksmode article on viewports at http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try touch events instead of mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with iPad. I had to add an e.preventDefault(); to the touchmove event. I did this only to the div where I was tracking interaction, *not* to the whole page.

```
element.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); };
```

No idea about your device, but might be worth a try.